# Statistical methods for adjusting heaping in birth weight data

Tags: dataset, methodology, finite-mixture-model

I have a birth weight data of children under aged 5 years (sample size, n=2000). Data comes from two sources:

1. Mothers recall (n=1500) and
2. Health card (n=500).

Naturally, mothers' recall data are highly heaped in different points due to digit preference. Health card data follows approximately normal distribution but recall data follows multi-modal distribution.

Is it good to analysis whole data set or only card data set? If we use whole data set than adjustment of heaping is needed. Which statistical method will help to adjust heaping?